# Determining comparable individual performance within a team sport

Tags: descriptive-statistics, weighted-data

i have collated a significant body data for a local badminton league (> 20000 indvidual games)
and while i have the means to extract data on a:

- per player
- per couple
- per team
- per club
- per season
- per division (across 4 or 5 divisions)
- per gameType (mixed, mens, ladies)

the piece i am missing is a way to understand how a specific individuals performance can be exracted, while taking into account the variables like; who they played with, which team the played for, what position they played. I feel like there is perhaps something to do with weighting the parameters, but i'm not sure where to start on that front.

I'd like to be able to compare individuals somehow, while factoring in the various variables, e.g player A is better than player B despite playing with certain people, or against certain team / other players etc.

### Extra info that may / may not be useful:

- a team consists of 3 men and 3 ladies forming various different pairings for a match consisting of 18 individual games
- a player usually plays for their own team, but can also be promoted to a higher team temporarily if required

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Aren’t they still arguing LeBron vs Michael and Brady vs Manning? I don’t get the sense that this is a solved problem or even one that has much in the way of guiding ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Do you believe that "performance" is a latent trait? If so then you can do either confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) or a Exploratory factor analysis (EFA)